# move to the begining of a page in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question, over moving to the beginning of a page. I have an image in the center of a page and I want when I click it move up to the same page??
How can I do that in angular??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make a focus to a div by adding a Tabindex to this div and in the same component, 
I could selected it and focus it. Without Tabindex, it does not work.

```
const div = document.getElementById('focusme');
  div.focus();
```

this is the div

```
<div id="focusme" tabindex="100"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Angular for any javascript for this.

That's a basic function of HTML called an [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Linking_to_an_element_on_the_same_page).

Stupid simple example:

```html
<body>

<div id="bla">hello</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div id="longcontent">

  

</div>

<script>

const longcontent = document.getElementById("longcontent");

let longStr = "";

for(let i = 0; i<1000; i++)
{
  longStr += "lorem ipsum yeeeha ";
}

longcontent.innerText = longStr;


</script>

<br/>

<a href="#bla">goto bla</a>

</body>
```

Comment: Actually I need it in angular since they are different components. So when I click in an image of a component, move to another component.

Comment: "to the beginning of a page" - add just a stupid blank container with an id to the app-component and reference it? You can still use anchors for that, but the part how to implement this into your app is up to you.